# Jackson XML deserialization to Java LinkedTreeMap Array

Tags: java, xml, dictionary, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson to read a XML to a Java LinkedTreeMap, here is my xml:

```
<Properties>
    <runList>
        <runID>6656</runID>
        <runID>6657</runID>
    </runList>
</Properties>
```

And

```
new XmlMapper().readValue("xml goes here...", Map.class);
```

I'm expecting to receive a LinkedTreeMap object like this:

```
{ properties => { runList => { 0=> 6656, 1=> 6657 } } }
```

Or

```
{ properties => { runList => { runID => { 0=> 6656, 1=> 6657 } } } }
```

But I'm receiving:

```
{ properties => { runList => { runID=> 6657 } } }
```

In other words the "runID" isn't considered as "an array" and the last smashes all others.
There is anyway to resolve the problem without create a class or maybe expressing the "XML array" a little bit different?

Comment: why use a gson internal class ?

Comment: what data type do you give Jackon as target deserialization? please share the code of the call to jackson

Comment: Basically: `new XmlMapper().readValue("xml here...", Map.class);`